How to update a table relationship in the database?
    async def update_user(self, telegram_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        async with self.session(bind=self.engine) as session:
            query = (update(User)
                     .where(User.telegram_id == telegram_id)
                     .values(kwargs))
            await session.execute(query)
            await session.commit()

I call this function from the Database class in this way:
new_interval = int(callback.data.replace('set_interval_', ''))
user_id = callback.from_user.id
user = await db.get_user(user_id)
user.options.interval = new_interval
await db.update_user(user_id, options=user.options)

I use sqlalchemy+aiosqlite modules for python

Sorry, I do not understand...what are you asking? What does it mean to "update a table relationship in the database"? Please clarify.

@s4D_t0y I apologize for the confusion, I have a table with a one-to-many relationship and I want to update this collection of objects from the second table. I hope I explained it correctly

try changing line to .values(**kwargs))

I've solved the problem. It is that I am trying to update MailOption (this is an options field type) through its User relationship, I should have just changed MailOptions by accessing it directly. Here is a new method that solved the problem:
